# Drupal 7 function db_insert() causes internal server error (500)

Tags: mysql, module, drupal-7

I am building an onsite payment method and among other things I need to save data to a custom db table, after recieving a callback from an external API service.

This is the function:

```
// callback from external service acting as client
function _api_callback() {
  global $user;
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), $assoc = true);
  $date = $date['year'] . '-' . $date['month'] . '-' . $date['day'];
  $timestamp = strtotime($date);
  db_insert('postback')
  ->fields(array(
    'user_id' => $user->uid,
    'data' => $data,
    'created_date' => $timestamp,
  ))
  ->execute(); // save data from external service
}
```

In the site's access log I can see that my site responds with a 500 code when the external callback arrives.

However if I comment out everything in that function the external callback recieves a 200 response code.

So there is some thing going wrong, when this callback is recieved. It's hard to debug since the callback from the external API service starts a whole new session.

The custom table "`postback`" was successfully created in the .install file of my custom module and I have checked in phpMyAdmin that the table is present and well. This is the `schema()` function in the .install file:

```
function module_payments_schema() {
  $schema['postback'] = array(
    'description' => 'Data saved from API postback URL.',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'Auto incremental id.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE),
      'user_id' => array(
        'description' => 'User id for the order.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE),
      'order_id' => array(
        'description' => 'Current order number.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0),
      'data' => array(
          'description' => 'Postback data from external API.',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 1020,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'default' => ''),
      'created_date' => array(
          'description' => 'Created date and time (yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s).',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'mysql_type' => 'DATETIME',
          'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
      ),
      'primary key' => array('id'),
    );

    return $schema;
  }
```

Anyone who can see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to format the date value like this...

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

... in order to work with the mysql DATETIME type.

So the working function now looks like this:

```
function _api_callback() {
  global $user;
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), $assoc = true);
  db_insert('postback')
  ->fields(array(
    'user_id' => $user->uid,
    'data' => $data,
    'created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  ))
  ->execute(); // save data from external service
}
```